# Issue with array_combine()

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays. The one's array key is another's value. Here is code:

```
$arr1 = array(
    'a' => 'apple',
    'b' => 'banana',
    'c' => 'pear',
);

$arr2 = array(
    'bird' => 'a',
    'dog' => 'b',
);
```

And my question, how to combine two arrays in one like:

```
$arr3 = array(
    'bird' => 'apple',
    'dog' => 'banana',
);
```

Is there have some array function to do this probably?

Comment: just loop the `$arr2` values into the keys of `$arr1` using foreach, `$arr1[$value_from_$arr2]` no need for special functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$arr3 = array();

foreach ($arr2 as $item => $value) {
  $arr3[$item] = $arr1[$value];
}
print_r($arr3);
```

something along those lines anyway.

If you literally want to merge the arrays, [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) will do the job fine.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**:  This is a fun way and matches the keys:

```
$arr3 = array_combine(array_intersect_key($k = array_flip($arr2), $arr1),
                      array_intersect_key($arr1, $k));
```

**Original with no key matching**:

Here's a way.  Doesn't matter which array is longer:

```
$arr3 = array_combine(array_slice(array_keys($arr2), 0, count($arr1)),
                      array_slice($arr1, 0, count($arr2)));
```